# how do i add a topic to a running kafka container using docker commands?

Tags: docker, groovy, apache-kafka

I have a kafka container started using following

```
docker run --detach --name kafka -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=192.168.1.89 --env ADVERVTISED_PORT=9092 --env AUTO.CREATE.TOPICS.ENABLE spotify/kafka
```

i can use docker logs kafka to see its started.

I then created a simple groovy script client producer to write some entries, however this keeps erroring with

```
> Sending metadata request {topics=[wills topic]} to node 0
> Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {wills topic=INVALID_TOPIC_EXCEPTION}
....
```

I have set the following properties in the client code

```
    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.1.89:9092" )   //Assign localhost id and external port (9092 int)
    props.put("acks", "all")                            //Set acknowledgements for producer requests.
    props.put("retries", 0)                             //If the request fails, the producer can automatically retry,
    props.put("batch.size", 16384)                      //Specify buffer size in config
    props.put("linger.ms", 1)                           //Reduce the no of requests less than 0
    props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432)                //The buffer.memory controls the total amount of memory available to the producer for buffering.
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put ("auto.create.topics.enable", true)       //enable auto topic creation

    producer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<String, String>(props)

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)))
    }
    println("Message sent successfully")
    producer.close()
```

but that does not not seem to enable auto topic creation. Given that i've spun the kafka server up as docker container - how does one administer that container instance once it is up and running using docker commands as the means to talk to the container

there is a note on the kafka site along the line of running a shell commend "bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test"

but its not easy to  see how one edits/interacts with this in container once its up.

how does one administer the kafka container instance in docker once it has been started.  otherwise what to you have to add to the docker run command to get topics pre created at startup

Advice greatfully received at this point

Answer (score 3):

The error message `{wills topic=INVALID_TOPIC_EXCEPTION}` is indicating that you are using `wills topic` as topic name.

A topic name cannot contain whitespaces. Try to rename to `wills_topic` and it should solve the problem.

This regex describes the legal characters for topic names (check [sources](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/common/Topic.scala#L24)):

```
val legalChars = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\._\\-]"
```

Use `docker exec -it <container-name> <command>` to launch the Kafka admin tools. Or just open a bash within your container `docker exec -it <container-name> bash` (see [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)).

Comment: bingo - removed whitespace and it worked.  however question still vagules stays as i'm running a containerised kafka - how do you administer it when all the config/scripts are locked away in the image ?

Comment: can you use docker commands to get that configuration and edit/change it.

Comment: you can user `docker exec`. See updated answer. Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: thanks Sebastian - let me go read the docker manual and kafka one and see what 'sentence' i need to construct

Answer (score 3):

use docker exec -it [container_id] /opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the above steps but facing some permission problems there is one more solution you can try in mine it worked perfectly

1. Download Apache Kafka binary file from the
   official website https://kafka.apache.org/downloads.
2. Open the terminal go through the path up to the folder. For eg
   /Users//Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.0.0
3. And run this command

   bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic 'topic-name'

If you want to create multiple topics with a single statement only

1. Create a text file first and save it topics.txt in Kafka folder in a format like ::

Eg:-

```
topic1:1:1

topic2:1:1
```

2. Open terminal up to the downloaded Kafka folder
3. Run the command with the help of awk

   awk -F':' '{ system("./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic=" $1 " --partitions=" $2 " --replication-factor=" $3) }' /topics.txt

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd post and mention another way if you are using a docker container, specifically the wurstmeister Kafka image. The solution above that uses a shell script didn't work for me as Kafka was not running in the container yet when the command was executed.

Instead, I used these environment variables in the `docker-compose.yml` file

```
KAFKA_PORT: 30000 # necessary for KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS to work
KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "topic1:1:1"
```